# How to attach a changing list of widgets to the top of the QVBoxLayout in PyQT6?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have **QWidget** with **QVBoxLayout** inside **QScrollArea** like this:

```
self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
self.widget = QWidget()
self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)

self.scroll = QScrollArea()
self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
```

Initially I have four buttons inside this scroll:

```
# ...Method to insert four buttons...
self.vbox.addStretch()
```

This keeps all 4 buttons at the top of the scroll area, but if i need to insert another four buttons after start of the program, I do this:

```
# ...Method to insert four buttons...
self.vbox.addStretch()
# ...Method to insert another four buttons...
```

And I get this:

[image]

But instead I would like to another four buttons to stick to the top as well. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: You could insert the widget *before* the stretch (the next to last item): `self.vbox.insertWidget(self.vbox.count() - 2, widget)`. Alternatively, don't use the stretch at all, but use `self.vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop).

Comment: I can't insert another four buttons before the stretch because they will be added later by user action. setAligment(Qt.AligmentFlag.AlignTop) worked for me, Thank you!

Comment: Whether the buttons will be added by user action or programmatically is irrelevant: if it didn't work it's because they were added just by using `addWidget()` ignoring the presence of the stretch; the above `insertWidget()` line will always work as soon as all widgets are always *inserted before* the stretch, if you are unsure about that, then just keep track of the stretch item just upon creation and always insert further widgets based on its index: `self.stretchItem = self.vbox.itemAt(self.vbox.count() - 1)` and then `self.insertWidget(self.vbox.indexOf(self.stretchItem), widget)`.

Comment: You could even make a QVBoxLayout subclass that automatically adds a stretch upon creation and override `addWidget()` so that it in reality always calls `insertWidget(max(0, self.count() - 2), widget)`.

Comment: Why not answer your own question?

Comment: @musicamante I tried insertWidget() and got what you said to me, Thank you very much! Could you please answer this question so I could choose it?

Comment: @Yonshoku I am posting a related answer. Note that I made a mistake about the index count: it should always be `count() - 1`, assuming that the stretch is always the final item added to the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard Qt layout managers use QLayoutItems as common abstract objects that are used to lay out everything. Those item objects can be widgets, nested layouts or *stretch* items.

To the layout manager, they are fundamentally treated in the same way, so a spacer item ([QSpacerItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qspaceritem.html)) has the same importance as any other.
What changes is its size policy, which is *expanding* for `addStretch()`, based on its stretch factor. The default factor is 0, meaning that if no other items in the layout have expanding directions, it will try to expand as much as possible.

If you added a stretch item to the bottom of a vertical layout (probably following [my own suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63438161/2001654)) you need to consider that you added a further item to the layout: whenever you add other items (like widgets using `addWidget()`) they will be appended *after* the stretch.

So, if you want to keep the widgets *pushed* on top when adding other items, while respecting the bottom spacer, you must consider its index, which is always equal to `layout.count() - 1`. This works similarly to the Python `list.insert()` function.

```py
# upon initialization
self.scrollContentLayout.addWidget(someWidget)
...
self.scrollContentLayout.addStretch()

# when called to add further widgets
indexOfSpacer = self.scrollContentLayout.count() - 1
self.scrollContentLayout.insertWidget(indexOfSpacer, anotherWidget)
```

Another similar possibility is to keep track of the added spacer item:

```py
...
self.scrollContentLayout.addStretch()
self.spacer = self.scrollContentLayout.itemAt(
    self.scrollContentLayout.count() - 1)

# then...
self.scrollContentLayout.insertWidget(
    self.scrollContentLayout.indexOf(self.spacer), anotherWidget)
```

Note that, for obvious reasons, the index must be always get dynamically (you cannot "store" it, as other items could be added/inserted in the meantime).

Finally, a simple possibility is to set the layout alignment, without any stretch/spacer item:

```py
self.scrollContentLayout.setAlignment(Qt.Alignment.AlignTop)
```

While this works for basic widgets, it may have different results if items are added with mixed stretch factors and size policies, so use it with care and awareness about these aspects.

I strongly suggest you to do some proper research about size hints, size policies and general layout management, but also consider to do further testing using Qt Designer and different widget types.